How to use clip-path and show the content beneath
I'd like to create an element as shown on the image below.

I tried to do this with CSS and clip-path by making the bottom part black and have a clip-path polygon (the triangle) on it, but it won't show the background beneath, just the clipped black background.


body {
  background: black;
}

.element {
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 4px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: end;
}

.triangle {
  width: 48px;
  height: 24px;
  z-index: 20;
  background: black;
  clip-path: polygon(50% 100%, 0 0, 100% 0);
}

.image {
  position: absolute;
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
<div class="element">
  <img class="image" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/14616449/pexels-photo-14616449.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1" />
  <div class="triangle" />
</div>



I assume I could also define a shape for the whole element and apply a clip-path on it, but the element needs to be responsive and I'm not sure if a hardcoded path will work with this.
Would appreciate any help 

Please edit your question to include the code you have tried (even though it doesn't work).

It's the image that needs clipping, not a separate element.
This snippet fixes the size of the triangle in px with the rest of the clipping being done relative to the size of the image (ie responsive).


body {
  background: black;
}

.element {
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 4px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: end;
}

.triangle {
  width: 48px;
  height: 24px;
  z-index: 20;
  background: black;
  clip-path: polygon(50% 100%, 0 0, 100% 0);
}

.image {
  position: absolute;
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% calc(100% - 24px), calc(50% + 24px) calc(100% - 24px), 50% 100%, calc(50% - 24px) calc(100% - 24px), 0 calc(100% - 24px));
}
<div class="element">
  <img class="image" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/14616449/pexels-photo-14616449.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1" />
</div>




Thanks! Yeah I knew about this but was thinking about something more readable, as this seems like magic on the first sight  But I eventually ended up with this exact solution as it seems there's no cleaner one.

It's just going round the image top, right side, part of not-quite-at-the-bottom, down at an angle to the bottom etc, the good thing being that it can be done in terms of % of the image width and height so it automatically responsive.
